# Where to create scenes?

Tags: unity, animation, models, level-design, 3dsmax

I'm starting to develop a 3D game with Unity and 3ds Max. Where do I create levels for my game? Do I create individual objects in 3ds Max and transfer them to Unity, or do I create the whole level in 3ds Max and transfer everything at once to Unity?

How about lightning? Animations? I would like to do these all in 3ds Max and use Unity to create the game mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

**Where do I create levels for my game?**

- File -> New Scene

**Do I create individual objects in 3ds Max and transfer them to Unity, or do I create the whole level in 3ds Max and transfer everything at once to Unity?**

- Short answer: Create individual objects and then transfer them to unity. 
   
  This is called modular design.
- Long answer: 
  http://www.realityisagame.com/archives/1871/two-approaches-to-making-large-lands-procedural-and-modular/ 

  http://udn.epicgames.com/Two/WorkflowAndModularity.html

**How about lightning? Animations? I would like to do these all in 3ds Max and use Unity to create the game mechanics.**

- Go ahead, do it! Unity is a great tool to join many different assets (animations, particles, models, etc..) into a single object by attaching them as components, the combination of all these things is called **GameObject**.

Answer (score 0):

Create individual models with modeling software (3ds Max), and import them as game objects in a Unity scene. That way you have more control over individual objects. Lightning also create in Unity.

You can make the level in 3ds Max, then import it as a whole in Unity, but it's (resource) expensive and your game mechanics don't have control over specific level objects (if you want them to be interactive)